# Unity | How to Change enums depending on main enum selection on Inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, enums

Well i have this Enums to be set on the inspector but i want to limite which enum will show depending on the Main Enum Selected to avoid using different enum than the desired

```
public MainSortEnum Sort;
public SecondaryTypeEnum1 Type1;
public SecondaryTypeEnum2 Type2;
public SecondaryTypeEnum3 Type3;
```

And the Enums

```
public enum MainSortEnum
{
    First,
    Second,
    Thirth,
}
public enum SecondaryTypeEnum1
{
    FirstType,
    SecondType,
    ThirthType,
}
public enum SecondaryTypeEnum2 
{
    FirstType,
    SecondType,
    ThirthType,
}
public enum SecondaryTypeEnum3
{
    FirstType,
    SecondType,
    ThirthType,
}
```

So i just want to Be able on the inspector on this script to select the desired enum based on the MainSortEnum, is this posible?

Comment: whats `SecondaryTypeEnum1`? Can u give an example?

Comment: oh sorry ill edit it, its SecondaryTypeEnum1 = SecondTypes

Comment: so if I choose `Sort` to be `Second`, what should `Type1` `Type2` and `Type3` be? I don't fly get what u r asking

Comment: Yeah if you chose on the inspector Sort to be First, then it should let you set Type1 and if you chose second it should disappear the other enums and only show you type2 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a [custom inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) for the class that these `enums` are in.

For instance, we will call such a class `MyClass`:

```
... //other namespaces
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MyClass))]
public class MyClassEditor : Editor {
    MyClass myClass;

    void OnEnable() {
        myClass = (MyClass)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        myClass.Sort = EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Sort", myClass.Sort);
        if (myClass.Sort == MainSortEnum.First)
            myClass.Type1 = EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Type 1", myClass.Type1);
        else if (myClass.Sort == MainSortEnum.Second)
            myClass.Type2 = EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Type 2", myClass.Type2);
        else
            myClass.Type3 = EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup("Type 3", myClass.Type3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh i think its that what im searching for, i will test and also thanks for the link, ill post back if worked, and thanks! :D

Comment: i think im missing something, i had To make this inside of the Actual Script im using or i have to transport everything from my class to Editor Folder?

Comment: @JorgeLuisLaraHernandez u don't have to change ur actual script. create a new folder called Editor, create a new script and paste this there. refer to the link I sent u and rly understand how custom inspectors work

Comment: i got it i was missunderstanding this, i now just had to display what i want and also saw that i can make a custom editor window, just last question, can i display values from an script on different editor windows? thanks man btw very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to have multiple `GameObjects` (3 in your case) and switch the `gameObject.SetActive(true/false)` based of the user input.

Comment: yea but the thing is that i want to be able to select from inspector and if something is selected on the first Enums, then on base of that will left you to chose from another enums based on first enum you selected

i mean if i select First from MainSortEnum then in the inspector it should let me chose from FirstTypes Enum, but if i select Fecond on MainSortEnum, FirstTypes enum field should disapear and appear SecondTypes